# RPGILE SQL XMLSERIALIZE example

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE STKBAL (CONO60 CHAR (2 ) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, STRC60 CHAR (2 ) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, PNUM60 CHAR (15 ) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, ACSU60 DECIMAL (15 ) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, SCSU60 DECIMAL (15 ) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT)
```

[image]

and need to export an XML with this format:

```
<fsxml>
    <FSITEM KEYCOLUMNS="item_code" KEYS="3000000" DETAILCODES="HEADER;TPALL" DETAILTABLES="FSITEM;FSITEMTPALL" VALIDCODES="ITEM;G.TECHPVAL">
        <ITEM_CODE>3000000</ITEM_CODE>
        <FSITEMTPALL>
            <PVALUE>3.1</PVALUE>
            <PARAM_CODE>WT_AVERAGE_COST</PARAM_CODE>
        </FSITEMTPALL>
        <FSITEMTPALL>
            <PVALUE>3.2</PVALUE>
            <PARAM_CODE>WT_STANDARD_COST</PARAM_CODE>
        </FSITEMTPALL>
        <FSITEMTPALL>
            <PVALUE>3.3</PVALUE>
            <PARAM_CODE>WF_STANDARD_COST</PARAM_CODE>
        </FSITEMTPALL>
        <FSITEMTPALL>
            <PVALUE>3.4</PVALUE>
            <PARAM_CODE>WF_AVERAGE_COST</PARAM_CODE>
        </FSITEMTPALL>
    </FSITEM>
    <FSITEM KEYCOLUMNS="item_code" KEYS="3000001" DETAILCODES="HEADER;TPALL" DETAILTABLES="FSITEM;FSITEMTPALL" VALIDCODES="ITEM;G.TECHPVAL">
        <ITEM_CODE>3000001</ITEM_CODE>
        <FSITEMTPALL>
            <PVALUE>3.11</PVALUE>
            <PARAM_CODE>WT_AVERAGE_COST</PARAM_CODE>
        </FSITEMTPALL>
        <FSITEMTPALL>
            <PVALUE>3.12</PVALUE>
            <PARAM_CODE>WT_STANDARD_COST</PARAM_CODE>
        </FSITEMTPALL>
        <FSITEMTPALL>
            <PVALUE>3.13</PVALUE>
            <PARAM_CODE>WF_STANDARD_COST</PARAM_CODE>
        </FSITEMTPALL>
        <FSITEMTPALL>
            <PVALUE>3.14</PVALUE>
            <PARAM_CODE>WF_AVERAGE_COST</PARAM_CODE>
        </FSITEMTPALL>
    </FSITEM>
</fsxml>
```

My code is almost there:

```
select                                                    
xmlserialize(content                                      
xmlelement(NAME "FSXML",                                  
xmlagg(                                                   
xmlelement(NAME "FSITEM",                                 
xmlattributes('item_code' as "KEYCOLUMNS",                
trim(pnum60) as "KEYS",                                   
'HEADER;TPALL' as "DETAILCODES",                          
'FSITEM;FSITEMPALL' as "DETAILTABLES",                    
'ITEM;G.TECHPVAL' as "VALIDCODES"),                       
xmlelement(NAME "ITEM_CODE", trim(pnum60)),               
 xmlelement(NAME "FSITEMPALL",                            
 xmlelement(NAME "PVALUE", trim(char(acsu60)) ),          
 xmlelement(NAME "PARAM_CODE", strc60||'_AVERAGE_COST'),  
 xmlelement(NAME "FSITEMPALL",                            
 xmlelement(NAME "PVALUE", trim(char(scsu60)) ),          
 xmlelement(NAME "PARAM_CODE", strc60||'_STANDARD_COST')) 
))))                                                      
 AS clob(15m) ccsid 37                                    
)as RESPONSE                                              
INTO :ResultCLOB                                          
FROM stkbal
```

The problem I have is my code repeats the ITEM_CODE tag for each stockroom, any clever way of doing this?
If I move the XML aggregate after the item tag it won't let me use the field pnum60.
Any help would be much appreciated :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, provide the `create table` statement and inserts of your sample data in it inside your question. Now it is not clear what sample column corresponds to what column in your query. Also do not use [images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/285557#285557), you can use [ASCII table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) (as suggested in [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) link on minimal reproducible example). And finally, you should tag your DBMS (despite the fact it can be guessed by familiar people)

Comment: CREATE TABLE STKBAL (CONO60 CHAR (2 ) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, 
STRC60 CHAR (2 ) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, PNUM60 CHAR (15 ) NOT NULL
WITH DEFAULT, ACSU60 DECIMAL (15 ) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, SCSU60  
DECIMAL (15 ) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT)

Comment: You can edit your question with the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66044720/edit) below it. It will be simple for others to read the question and get all the input from it, not from comments. But I still cannot map the `CONO60` column, for example, to something in sample data.

Comment: CONO60 is the Company "AA" in sample data